# monkey-patching/decorating/wrapping an entire python module

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I would like, given a python module, to monkey patch all functions, classes and attributes it defines. Simply put, I would like to *log* every interaction a script I do not directly control has with a module I do not directly control. I'm looking for an elegant solution that will not require prior knowledge of either the module or the code using it.

I found several high-level tools that help wrapping, decorating, patching etc... and i've went over the code of some of them, but I cannot find an elegant solution to create a proxy of any given module and automatically proxy it, as seamlessly as possible, except for appending logic to every interaction (record input arguments and return value, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*in case someone else is looking for a more complete proxy implementation*

Although there are several python proxy solutions similar to those OP is looking for, I could not find a solution that will also proxy *classes* and arbitrary *class objects*, as well as automatically *proxy* functions *return values* and *arguments*. Which is what I needed.

I've got some code written for that purpose as part of a full proxying/logging python execution and I may make it into a separate library in the future. If anyone's interested you can find the core of the code in a [pull request](https://github.com/nirizr/pytest-idapro/pull/35). Drop me a line if you'd like this as a standalone library.

My code will automatically return wrapper/proxy objects for any proxied object's attributes, functions and classes. The purpose is to log and replay some of the code, so i've got the equivalent "replay" code and some logic to store all proxied objects to a json file.